# Can I verify if it is my Chrome-Extension accessing my remote server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way that my remote server can know that the chrome-extension contacting it is indeed the chrome-extension I have developed and not another chrome-extension trying to access my remote server?

Maybe certificates or private keys somehow?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: I would try [security.se]. This one is a tough question, since all of your client code and data is exposed to the user (unless you use some clever crypto in a compiled PNaCl module).

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. You can be reasonably sure though using an Auth 2 style setup flow.

On startup if you extension is not configured show users a setup/login button. This button opens a URL to your server. The server generates a public/private key pair and redirects the user to the extension URI with they private key. E.g. `chrome-extension://xyz/callback.html?key=123` where the key gets saved locally. If you only redirect to that specific origin you can be reasonably sure that only your extension gets the secret. Every request should include the key or a signature based on the key. There is however nothing stopping a user from copying the key and using it in their own server/app/extension.